# Keytool without keystore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have a question about keytool..

I would to use this command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks -destkeystore foo.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Can I don't specify the srckeystore? I need this request because I don't know my keystore that  I use.. :)
I created  the certificate in this way:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
```

so, I don't have specified the keystore...In this way, Keytool which keystore will use?

Comment: This is a Java tools question. It has nothing to do with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `keytool` command to generate a keystore and you do not have a `-keystore` option, it will create the keystore in the default location, which is the user's home directory.  And the filename will be ".keystore".

For the `-importkeystore` option, `-srckeystore` is required, so you will have to give the path to the ".keystore" file that you created.

To avoid this confusion, when you create a new keystore, give it a known filename by using the `-keystore` option.

For example:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore foo.jks
```

Now your command to convert it to a PKCS12 keystore should work.

For more details, see the [keytool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

Answer (score 0):

Never actually tried it but if my memory serves me right the default keystore is called keystore.jks

You can probably run the following to be sure;

```
keytool -v -list
```

and it should tell you the keystore type.